# IF/ELSE returning multiple error levels in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Good afternoon, I am attempting to copy a directory to another directory, and have the whole process reported in the log. Right now, the log gets a report of success AND a 9009 error.

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe /E /I /Y "\\network_share\program\source\*" "C:\Program Files\program"
    IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 (echo %DATE% - %TIME% - Success!!!  >> \\network_share\program\logs\%username%.log)
    ELSE (
    echo %DATE% - %TIME% - failure - %errorlevel%  >> \\network_share\program\logs\%username%.log
    Exit /b 1
    )
```

previous to this I do whats below to confirm the folder exsists;

```
IF EXIST "C:\program files\program" (echo %DATE% - %TIME% - program folder already exsists  >> \\network_share\program\logs\%username%.log 
    ELSE (
    md "C:\Program Files\program"
    echo %DATE% - %TIME% - Folder didn't exist but may now %errorlevel%  >> \\network_share\program\logs\%username%.log
```

The files get moved, but it still gets hung up on error code 9009. So confused. I use cmtrace to monitor the log and once batch hits that 9009 it closes leaving about 10 more things left to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `IF /?`:

```
The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.  For
example:

    IF EXIST filename. (
        del filename.
    ) ELSE (
        echo filename. missing.
    )
```

Indeed, in both your examples, error code `9009` means:

```
==> ELSE
'ELSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

==> echo %errorlevel%
9009
```

(Note that string `==>` is my [`cmd.exe` command prompt](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) `prompt $Q$Q$G$S`)

Comment: Yep, I was close, but that is EXACTLY what it needed thank you very much.